# PL/SQL Statement ignored error occurs

Tags: oracle, plsql

in bellow code PL/SQL Statement ignored error occurs error accurs line is in bold and italic fonts

```
create or replace
TRIGGER TRGBILLINGADDRESS 
AFTER UPDATE ON TBLMACCOUNTADDRESS 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    add1 VARCHAR2(100);
    add2 VARCHAR2(100);
    cityid VARCHAR2(75);
    stateid VARCHAR2(75);
    pincd VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN

   SELECT address1,address2,city_id,state_id,pincode 
   INTO add1,add2,cityid,stateid,pincd  FROM wom.tbltaddress ta  WHERE ta.ID IN (
          SELECT vbac.billing_address_id
          FROM wom.vw_billaddresschange vbac, wom.tbltaddress ita
          WHERE vbac.billing_address_id = ita.ID
          AND vbac.lcid = parlcid);
   ***IF add1 = :NEW.address1 AND add2 = :NEW.address2 AND  cityid = :NEW.cityid AND  stateid = :NEW.stateid AND  pincode = :NEW.zip THEN***            
          dbms_output.put_line('Address Already Exist in tbltaddress table');
   ELSE
          UPDATE wom.tbltaddress ta
                   SET ta.address1 = :NEW.address1,
                       ta.address2 = :NEW.address2,
                      ***ta.city_id = :NEW.cityid*,**
                       ta.country_id = 'CTR0001',
                       ta.state_id = :NEW.stateid,
                       ta.pincode = :NEW.zip
                 WHERE ta.ID IN (
                          SELECT vbac.billing_address_id
                            FROM wom.vw_billaddresschange vbac, wom.tbltaddress ita
                           WHERE vbac.billing_address_id = ita.ID
                                 AND vbac.lcid = parlcid);
   END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your variable is declared as `pincd`, not `pincode`. `pincode` is the field in the table.